# Flask set variable is not updating value in (HTML)

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to change the position of a svg tag, after every svg is created inside a bucle, but my variable x_value_weeks is not updating inside my loop, and it just stays with the same value.

I declare my variable

```
{% set x_value_weeks = 5 %}
```

I set the variable outside the bucle and inside the bucle I update it using

```
{% set x_value_weeks = x_value_weeks + 10 %}
```

full code

```
<svg class="user-streak-svg-container" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    {% set x_value_weeks = 5 %}
    {% for week in weeks %}
        <svg class="user-streak-svg-column" x="{{ x_value_weeks }}">
           ....
        </svg>
        {% set x_value_weeks = x_value_weeks + 10 %}
    {% endfor %}
</svg>
```

Comment: Why not `for x_value_weeks in range(5, 550, 10)`?

Comment: w_value_weeks its just a variable to positionate my svg in a incrementing x position of 10, and my weeks value, will be an object of the weeks that will be displayed in the application, I am creating an svg that shows the activity of an user, like the github commits green table for example, so every week is a column with certain object info that i m no displaying yet. And x_value_weeks should be another variable to positionate the x value of every new column. (I hope this makes sense)

Comment: You should update the snippet to show that `week` is also used for something other than iteration.

Comment: but this give me an idea that I could nest another loop withing weeks which will just loop in step 10 as your example, and his value will be used for the X position of my svg item, but I guess that create a bucle is too much, when I could just have a variable inside that increments in 10 by 10, as I am trying.

Comment: If you nest loops it multiplies the number of iterations, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<svg class="user-streak-svg-container" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    {% for week in range(100) %}
        <svg class="user-streak-svg-column" x="{{ 5 + week * 10 }}">
           <!-- Your SVG content here -->
        </svg>
    {% endfor %}
</svg>
```

`x="{{ 5 + week * 10 }}"` calculates the x position dynamically for each iteration in the loop.

Comment: yes that's perfect, thank you, I m using a range as an example, since I havent develope the weeks object, but I could iterate through with a enumerate() to get the index, and replace it in that week value, thank you so much !.